# Joint Discret Random Variable PMF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to solve the following problem:

[image]

I'm not sure what it means to plot the PMF? Can someone please explain the process of plotting it?

What is a valid joint PMF?

Comment: They want you to show a graph of the function. The $a$ that makes all the probabilities add up to $1$ is the $a$ that makes $f$ a valid PMF (probability mass function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly solve (b) so that you will know the value of a at the time that you will plot the function. $f$ is a joint valid pmf if (i) $f(k,l)\ge0$ and (ii) $\sum f(k,l)=1$. So, in order that all the values of $f$ add up to 1 (already mentioned in the comments), we solve the equation  $$1=a(1^1+1^2+1^3+2^1+2^2+2^3+3^1+3^2+3^3)=56a$$ which implies that $$a=\frac{1}{56}$$ that is $$f_{K,L}(k,l)=\begin{cases}\\\frac{1}{56}k^l, & k \in \{1,2,3\}, l \in \{1,2,3\}\\ \\0, & \text{o.w.}\end{cases}$$
Now for (a) you need a three dimensional shape. One dimension for k, one for l and one for $f(k,l)$. You will have 9 dots that differ from zero in total in the graph. Everywhere else the function $f$ is zero.[image]